# How to check a text file to see if it contains the value of a string variable

Tags: groovy

i have created a file named "list.txt". this is the content of list.txt:

```
homer
marge
maggie
lisa
bart
```

the script to read the content looks like this:

```
def simpsons = new File('list.txt')
def lines = simpsons.readLines()

lines.each {String line -> println line}
println "###############################"
String test = "bart"

if(lines.contains("$test")){
    println "$test is in list"
}
else{
    println "$test is not in the list"
}
```

the script should check if the list contains the value specified in the string variable "test" but the check fails. the output is the following:

```
homer
marge
maggie
lisa
bart
###############################
bart is not in the list
```

obviously it is not possible to pass the "test" variable as a parameter in
lines.contains() like I did, but how can you pass it then?

Comment: Tried `lines.contains(test)`?

Comment: Maaan, thanks! for some reason i didn't try this option

Answer (score 0):

If you change your check to `lines.contains(test)` it will work perfectly.

Why?

The problem is that `lines.contains("$test")` will eventually call `String.equals(Object obj)` and although could seem a little bit strange at first but `test.equals("$test")` returns false as `"$test"` is a GString and not a String.